# JAVA : how to get the first N SORTED entries in a directory?

Tags: java, file, sorting, io

I need to retrieve N entry max.

I need to sort the entries by name (with directories being first).

I'd like to use the Files.newDirectoryStream() instead of File.listFiles() to avoid creating a possibly large list (and to have a way to stop it in case the number of files is really huge).

What would be the most efficient way of doing that? I guess I need to iterate the whole stream and keep a bounded sorted list to keep only N entry.

Thx.

Comment: What did you try so far? Why would you need to iterate the entire stream instead of just using `limit()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create empty `ArrayList<File>`
2. Iterate over directory entries and put them into list until it have M elements or all entries are read (M >> N)
3. Use quickselect algorithm to move top N entries to the beginning of the list
4. Trim list to N elements
5. Repeat steps 2–4 untill all the entries are read
6. Sort the list